# How can modify dataframe list elements in a loop Python?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, enumerate

I have 2 dataframes in a list, I mean 'Intraday_Mape' and 'Day_Ahead_Mape' are dataframes.
These dataframes contains hourly data but I want to change them into monthly data. When I am doing this, I want to use for loop because, I'll deal with more dataframes in the future.

```
report_dfs = [Intraday_Mape, Day_Ahead_Mape]

for i, _ in enumerate(report_dfs):
    report_dfs[i]=report_dfs[i].index.name = 'Date'
    report_dfs[i]=report_dfs[i].resample('M').mean().reindex(annual_date_range, fill_value = 0)
    report_dfs[i]=report_dfs[i].round(2)
```

When I print Intraday_Mape, I have still hourly data, it is not change.
How can I achieve modified dataframes out of the for loop?
I mean, when I print Intraday_Mape:

```
print(Intraday_Mape)
```

I got old one. How do I permanently change these datasets outside of the for loop?

Comment: `df.groupby(df['date_col'].dt.month)['values'].mean())` ?

Comment: show an example of your DataFrame and your expected output

Comment: I have not problem in this step, in for loop I achieve modified dataframes but I want to call them out of the for loop with their names.

Answer (score 0):

You should say `print(report_dfs[0])` and `print(report_dfs[1])` to get the dataframes. You are not actually modifying the named dataframes. You are modfiying the dataframes inside the list you created. That is `report_dfs`.

Comment: Mehmed, ben bu dataframe'leri ismi ile çağırmam gerek yani modify etmem gerekiyor ki for loop'un dışında çağırabileyim bunu nasıl yapabilirim peki?

Comment: You could reassign them individually, like Intraday_Mape = report_dfs[0] and Day_Ahead_Mape = report_dfs[1]  but I guess you can't do that for some reason? Do you have dataframes more than just these two ?

Comment: I found similar posts like yours but non of them actually answers your question. I am also not able to figure out how to do that in a loop. Sorry HACI!

Comment: I understand you're really trying to help. Eyvv!

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try the for loop below (assuming report_dfs represents a list of data frames, not a list of strings):

```
for r in report_dfs:
    r = r.index.name = 'Date'
    r = r.resample('M').mean().reindex(annual_date_range, fill_value = 0)
    r = r.round(2)
```

Comment: Or if report_dfs is a list of strings. You may use this: reports_dfs = [*do what you need to here* for r in report_dfs]. This will create a list of data frames with the changes you need.